# How to access swift class in other module of objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift

How can i access that dummy class.swift in my sdksdk module and use it in ViewController.m file. any suggestion [structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGGiR.png)

in dummy class there is a var name = "sid"

and i want to fetch that in my objective c class

dummy project link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PpJfdAlkT8kPhbxnFvJ2DyshvaD6K_mD

Comment: Try to specify how you want to use it. 
If you want to use any class inside another module you need to perform some sort of injection, use interface or callback from module and call function frin outside of module.

Comment: @DenisKakačka i have edited can u pls check again.

Comment: can you put the accessing code in here, and then describe a failure, error, etc. TIA.

Comment: @benc there is no error, i just can't access swift file to my other module. aren't u able to download the dummy project ?

Comment: I can't download project you linked. Its ask for permission

Comment: @DenisKakačka  https://github.com/SiddhantVmax/dummyProject.git think for help pls check this

Comment: Your solution is bad in general, If you want to work in your case with `sdkSdk` it must be framework, right now its just another projects laying inside project and there is no way to use code from one in another.

Comment: suppose its an sdkskd is a framework so how can i ?  @DenisKakačka i have updated the repo can u check, thanks for your time

Comment: I updated my answer with example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your `sdkSDK` module to be a framework, add it to you project. After that you can `import sdkSDK` in any of your `Pracs` classes or inject things to `sdkSDK`, best way I found to communicate from SDK to App is to use callbacks.
I did simple example in `Swift` but in your case there will be no difference if you will combine `Swift` and `ObjC`.

First - add SDK to Project.
[image]

Code inside SDK:

```
public class SDKDummyProvider {

    public var sdkSurnameDidChanged: ((_ text: String) -> Void)?

    var surname = "Siddhant" {
        willSet {
            // When you change surname its calls closure in `willSet`
            sdkSurnameDidChanged?(newValue)
        }
    }

    public init(name: String) {
        print("Name from Pracs: \(name)")
    }
}
```

Code inside Project:

```
import sdkSDK

class AppDummy {
    var name = "Name"

    let sdkProvider: SDKDummyProvider

    init() {
        // This is how you 'inject' name to SDK
        sdkProvider = SDKDummyProvider(name: name)

        // This is how SDK module will tell to Pracs that name has changed.
        sdkProvider.sdkSurnameDidChanged = { newName in
            print(newName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: u wrote AppDummy i wanted in objc class.

Comment: Principle is the same for Objective-C